# c pthreads abort poll in infinite loop from main thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pipe, polling

In a thread I am using poll to block the thread until there is something to read, but I need to close the thread and cleanup when a signal is captured by my program.

I tried to use pipe and add the read end of the pipe to the set of file descriptors used by poll. Then when I decided that I wish to abort the poll and exit out of the thread, I'd simply write some data to the write end of the pipe.

It seems very straight forward but apparently it isn't as simple as I thought. Here is the general logic behind it:

```
int pipefd[2];

int main(){ 
    // create thread and init mutex etc...
    pipe(pipefd); // init pipe

    BLOCK_UNTIL_SIGINT(); // block until a SIGINT signal is received

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mx); // unlock mutex

    write(pipefd[1], NULL, 8); // write some data to the write end of the pipe
    close(pipefd[1]);
    // cleanup
}

/* Returns 1 (true) if the mutex is unlocked, which is the
 * thread's signal to terminate. 
 */
int needQuit(pthread_mutex_t *mtx) {
  switch(pthread_mutex_trylock(mtx)) {
    case 0: /* if we got the lock, unlock and return 1 (true) */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(mtx);
      return 1;
    case EBUSY: /* return 0 (false) if the mutex was locked */
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}


void *thread_func(void *param){
    struct pollfd p[2];
    pthread_mutex_t *mx = (pthread_mutex_t*) param;

    bzero(&p, sizeof(p));

    p[0].fd = fd; // file descriptor to file I wish to read from when there's data to read
    p[0].revents = 0;
    p[0].events = POLLIN|POLLPRI;

    p[1] = p[0];
    p[1].fd = pipefd[0];

    while (!needQuit(mx)) { // repeat until mutex is unlocked
        if (poll(p, 1, -1)) { // block until there is something to read from the pipe or file
            // do something
        }
    }
    // cleanup
}
```

I'd think poll would return when I write some data on the write end of the pipe but absolutely nothing happens...

Comment: `while (!mutexIsUnlocked(mx))` is not a valid synchronization method. I'm not clear what you're trying to do with it, but it doesn't make sense as-is.

Comment: @R.. Now I added the function (taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7963143))

Comment: You could consider using `pthread_cancel()`.  If your thread is cancellable (the default) and its cancellation type is `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS` (*not* the default) then cancelling your thread should break it out of the `poll()`.  Note that thread cancellation is implemented via signals on some systems (notably Linux), which may require extra attention if you're going to do it from a signal handler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I need to execute some commands before exiting the thread, but I need to escape the infinite loop first. So I believe it wouldn't work to cancel the thread that way.

Comment: @Linus, it may be that thread cancellation won't do what you need, but do be aware that pthreads has provisions for threads to clean up when cancelled.  See `pthread_cleanup_push()` if you're interested.

Comment: @Linus, alternatively, consider signaling your thread directly, and handling the `EINTR` you should expect `poll()` to return in that case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Signaling has an inherent race: if the signal is sent before `poll` is entered, it will not cause `EINTR`. The nonstandard `ppoll` in Linux can solve this, but OP's solution with pipes is arguably nicer.

Comment: Good catch, @R.. .  For what it's worth, I like the OP's pipe idea just fine, except that I cannot explain why it's not working.  That's why I'm throwing out alternatives.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Because OP is passing `nfds=1` rather than `nfds=2` to `poll`...

Comment: @R.. Wow, thanks... It was that simple, off by one error.. Thanks, it's working now :)

Comment: You don't actually need the weird use of a mutex in `needQuit()`, a simple flag variable that you set when you read something from the pipe would do.