# Is pthread_cond_wait completely signal safe?

Tags: android, linux, pthreads, signals

There is a piece of code running in my stack which waits on pthread_cond_wait. A signal is send to the same process but there is no "pthread_cond_signal" code in the signal handler to notify the pthread_cond_wait but still pthread_cond_wait is released. There are other threads who usually does "pthread_cond_wait" to release the wait but none of them are active at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_cond_wait()` can wake up at *any time*, even if it has not been signalled.

This is called a "spurious wakeup", and correct code must handle this - in most cases, the correct way to call `pthread_cond_wait()` is within a loop structured like:

```
while (!condition_waiting_for)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
```

Where `condition_waiting_for` is the condition over your program's shared state that your thread is waiting to become true (for example, "job queue is not empty").

When you structure your `pthread_cond_wait()` call like this, spurious wakeups - including wakeups that might be caused by signals - do not affect the correctness of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The `pthread_cond_wait` can be signaled by `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

Also, a pthread can be cancelled with `pthread_cancel`, which sends a cancellation request to the thread. After sending the request to cancel the thread you should check the return code to confirm that the thread was actually cancelled.

There's a good thread discussing [how to kill a pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961029/how-can-i-kill-a-pthread-that-is-in-an-infinite-loop-from-outside-that-loop).

Comment: My question is different. I'm asking whether it is safe from other signals like user-defined ones. Because I know for a fact sem_wait is not completely signal safe, checkout https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait  --> A signal handler always interrupts a blocked call to one of these functions, regardless of the use of the sigaction(2) SA_RESTART flag